# Apex Function Parameter is always null

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Got an Apex function that takes in a String as a parameter (which is the current page's recordId - Opportunity Id) and I want to query the Opportunity for any Product__c objects its linked to via a lookup field. 
However I've noticed that the String Parameter of the Apex function is never populated and thus I always get the error 'Argument cannot be null'. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" 
            controller="ProductSelectionCtrl" access="global">


<aura:attribute name="products" type="Product__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectedProductId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="asset_classes" type="Product__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="sub_asset_classes" type="Product__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="macro_strategies" type="Product__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="strategies" type="Product__c[]"/> 
<aura:attribute name="filterObject" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="pageSize" type="integer" default="18"/>
<aura:attribute name="page" type="integer"/>
<aura:attribute name="pages" type="integer"/>
<aura:attribute name="total" type="integer"/>
<aura:attribute name="openModalTrue" type="Boolean"/>




<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<aura:handler event="c:ProductFilterChange" action="{!c.productFilterChangeHandler}"/>

<!-- event that recieves the product Id from an onlcik action on the ProductTile cmp -->
<aura:handler event="c:ProductGetProdIdEvent" action="{!c.saveProductToOpportunity}"/>

<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.asset_classes}" action="{!c.onAssetClassFilterChange}"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.sub_asset_classes}" action="{!c.onSubAssetClassFilterChange}"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.macro_strategies}" action="{!c.onMacroStrategyFilterChange}"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.strategies}" action="{!c.onStrategyFilterChange}"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.openModalTrue}" action="{!c.onModalInitialization}"/>




<aura:registerEvent name="ProductModalOpen" type="c:ProductSelectorInitialModal" />


<div class="slds-m-right_xx-large">
               <div>        
                   <ul aura:id="list" class="slds-grid slds-grid--pull-padded slds-wrap">          
                       <aura:iteration items="{!v.products}" var="product" indexVar="index">                    
                           <c:ProductTile product="{#product}" index="{#index}"/>                   
                       </aura:iteration>
                   </ul>                    
                   <c:Paginator page="{!v.page}" pages="{!v.pages}" total="{!v.total}" label="products"
                                previousPage="{!c.onPreviousPage}" nextPage="{!c.onNextPage}"/>

               </div>
             </div>
```

**Controller**

```
 ({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {


    var filterObject = {
        searchKey: '',
        assetClass: '',
        subAssetClass: '',
        strategy: '',
        macroStrategy : ''
    }

    component.set("v.filterObject", filterObject);
    //sets the openModal attribute to true which in turn will trigger an event to open the Initial Modal screen
    component.set("v.openModalTrue", "True");

    helper.loadProducts(component);





},

           onPreviousPage: function(component, event, helper) {
                          var page = component.get("v.page") || 1;
    var direction = event.getParam("direction");
    page = page - 1;
    helper.loadProducts(component, page);
           },

           onNextPage: function(component, event, helper) {
                          var page = component.get("v.page") || 1;
    var direction = event.getParam("direction");
    page = page + 1;
    helper.loadProducts(component, page);
    debugger;
           },


onModalInitialization: function(component, event, helper) {
    /*need to figure out a way to check if the opp (current record id) has a Product__c connected to it)*/
    var modalEventFire = $A.get("e.c:ProductSelectorInitialModal");        

    helper.getLinkedProduct(component);
    debugger;


                          /*
    if(modalCount == 0){
           modalEventFire.setParams({"openModal" : "True"});
           modalEventFire.fire();

    }else{
        component.set("openModalTrueCount", 1);
    }*/
},



productFilterChangeHandler: function(component, event, helper) {

    var filterObject = component.get("v.filterObject");
    if (event.getParam("searchKey") !== undefined) {
                   filterObject.searchKey = event.getParam("searchKey");

    }
    if (event.getParam("assetClass") !== undefined) {
        filterObject.assetClass = event.getParam("assetClass");
    }
    if (event.getParam("subAssetClass") !== undefined) {
        var subAssetClass = event.getParam("subAssetClass");
                   filterObject.subAssetClass = event.getParam("subAssetClass");
    }
    if (event.getParam("strategy") !== undefined) {
        var strategy = event.getParam("strategy");

                   filterObject.strategy = event.getParam("strategy");
    }
    if (event.getParam("macroStrategy") !== undefined) {
        var macroStrategy = event.getParam("macroStrategy");
                   filterObject.macroStrategy = event.getParam("macroStrategy");
    }
    if (event.getParam("focusFunds") !== undefined) {

                   filterObject.focusFund = event.getParam("focusFunds");
    }
    if (event.getParam("defendFunds") !== undefined) {

                   filterObject.defendFund = event.getParam("defendFunds");
    }

    if (event.getParam("introductionFunds") !== undefined) {

                   filterObject.introductionFund = event.getParam("introductionFunds");
    }

    console.log(filterObject);
    helper.loadProducts(component);
},

           onAssetClassFilterChange: function(component, event, helper){             

                   var acOptionChange = $A.get("e.c:ProductSelectorAssetClassFilterEvent");     
                   var resultingACs = component.get("v.asset_classes");     
                   var acOptionChangesValues = acOptionChange.getParam("assetClassTypes");
                   acOptionChange.setParams({"assetClassTypes" : resultingACs});
                   acOptionChange.fire(); 

           },

           onSubAssetClassFilterChange: function(component, event, helper){               

        var sacOptionChange = $A.get("e.c:ProductSelectorSubAssetClassFilterEvent");     
        var resultingSACs = component.get("v.sub_asset_classes");
        var sacOptionChangesValues = sacOptionChange.getParam("subAssetClassTypes");
        sacOptionChange.setParams({"subAssetClassTypes" : resultingSACs});            
        sacOptionChange.fire(); 
           },


           onMacroStrategyFilterChange: function(component, event, helper){                 
        var macStratOptionChange = $A.get("e.c:ProductSelectorMacroStrategyFilterEvent");
        var resultingMacStrats = component.get("v.macro_strategies");
        var macStratOptionChangesValues = macStratOptionChange.getParam("macroStrategyTypes");
        macStratOptionChange.setParams({"macroStrategyTypes" : resultingMacStrats});
        macStratOptionChange.fire(); 

           },


           onStrategyFilterChange: function(component, event, helper){  
        var stratOptionChange = $A.get("e.c:ProductSelectorStrategyFilterEvent");
        var resultingStrats = component.get("v.strategies");
        var stratOptionChangesValues = stratOptionChange.getParam("strategyTypes");
        stratOptionChange.setParams({"strategyTypes" : resultingStrats});
        stratOptionChange.fire(); 

           },


           saveProductToOpportunity: function(component, event, helper){
        var selectProdId = event.getParam("prodId");
        var oppId = component.get("v.recordId");
        helper.saveProductToOpportunity(component, selectProdId, oppId);

           }
```

})

**Helper**

```
getLinkedProduct: function(component){

    var action = component.get("c.getProducts");        
    var oppId = component.get("v.recordId");        
    action.setParam({
        "currentOppId": oppId            
    });        
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
            var result = response.getReturnValue();                
        }    
    });        

    $A.enqueueAction(action);

},
```

**Apex Controller (part of it)**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Opportunity> getProducts(String currentOppId) {

    Id oppId = Id.valueOf(currentOppId);
    System.debug('oppId: ' + oppId);
    Opportunity[] linkedProduct = [Select Id, Product__c from Opportunity 
    where Id =: oppId];
    System.debug('linkedProduct: ' + linkedProduct);
    return linkedProduct;
}
```

Comment: can you add lightning component code and also, where you have placed this component?

Comment: are you getting "currentOppId" null in sever side???

Comment: @SFDC_learner yes

Comment: no need to do type coversion just pass string value to your query .Opportunity[] linkedProduct = [Select Id, Product__c from Opportunity 
    where Id =: currentOppId];....comment oppId

Comment: I'am not seeing 

> 
aura:attribute "recordId" in your lightning component.

Then how you are accessing component.get("v.recordId") in your Javascript side.if you access like that you will get null value in your server side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a simple typo in your JavaScript controller. `action.setParam()`, with that object parameter, should be `action.setParams()`, plural.

Comment: Thankyou @David but I've tried that with no results

Comment: add force:hasRecordId interface ::<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName"> and also correct it your action.setParams() [david already mentioned it]

Comment: Very nice @David.Very nice catch  :)